# What is the syntax for Class< ? extends class_name> in kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin

I am trying to make an Arraylist that accepts any class variable that inherited from Word_Class but it doesn't work :

```
var lst = ArrayList<Class<Word_Class>>();
lst.add(Class<Noun_Class>);
```

---

I am looking for the syntax for Class< ? extends class_name> in kotlin

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [out type projection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections) in Kotlin. it is equivalent to `? extends T` in Java, for example:

```
//                         v--- out type projection
var lst = ArrayList<Class<out Word_Class>>()
```

To get a Java class you should use `KClass#java`, for example:

```
//                 v--- get a KClass instance
lst.add(Noun_Class::class.java)
//                         ^--- get java.lang.Class instance
```

Comment: @user8459720 Not at all. Glad it helped you.